# C++ comparing input string with a string gives me a warning of conversion from double to int - possible data loss

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have to write a program that asks user for weight and a planet name. Program has to output how much user would weight on that planet. For some reason i get errors: " '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data.

Before i was trying to use (planet == Mercury) but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
    // ConsoleApplication5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "ConsoleApplication5.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Assignment 05" << endl;


    int weight = 0;
    string planet = "";
    int weightOnplanet;
    string entry = "You entered a weight of ";

    string Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto;

    cout << "Please Enter Weight <as an integer of pounds>: " << endl;
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Please Enter Planet name <ie: Earth>: " << endl;
    cin >> planet;
    cout << entry << weight << " and a planet name of " + planet << endl;



    if (planet == Mercury)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 0.4155;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Venus)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 0.8975;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Earth)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 1.0;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Mars)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 0.3507;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Jupiter)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 2.5374;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Saturn)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 1.0677;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Uranus)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 0.8947;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Neptune)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 1.1794;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else if (planet == Pluto)
    {
        weightOnplanet = weight * 0.0899;
        cout << "On a " + planet + " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnplanet << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Unknown Planet" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you get is for

```
weightOnplanet = weight * 0.4155;
```

Since `weightOnPlanet` is `int` and `weight * 0.4155` is double you will be loosing precision.You probably want `weightOnplanet` to be `double` and not `int`.

Just to mention `if (planet == Mercury)` would be comparing `planet` to an empty string which is why you would get undesired result, until you do what @ErrorAtLine0 mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed "warning" alert.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i do appreciate that - since i just started learning C++.

Answer (score 3):

Each planet variable (Mercury, Venus, etc) should have an actual value such as:

```
Mercury = "Mercury";
```

A string doesnt initialize with the name of the variable, you have to actually give it a value.

You don't even have to have a variable for every planet. You could just do this:

```
if(planet == "Mercury")
```